# Why the destrcution is called twice？

Tags: c++, gdb

I have got one crash. and I use gdb to analyze the stack,I got the below result.

```
13 0x00007f423c6e9670 in ?? ()
#14 0x00007f42340496d8 in ?? ()
#15 0x0000000003cef568 in ?? ()
#16 0x00000000008da861 in HuffmanEnd ()
#17 0x00000000008d4a83 in faacEncClose ()
#18 0x00000000004fd797 in RecorderSession::~RecorderSession   (this=0x7f423404ea90, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>)
at /root/Desktop/VideoRecoder/2.0/src/videorecorder/RecorderSession.cpp:203
#19 0x00000000004fdae9 in RecorderSession::~RecorderSession (this=0x7f423404ea90, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>)
at /root/Desktop/VideoRecoder/2.0/src/videorecorder/RecorderSession.cpp:203
#20 0x0000000000500d0b in RecorderSession::OnHangup (this=0x7f423404ea90) at /root/Desktop/VideoRecoder/2.0/src/videorecorder/RecorderSession.cpp:295
#21 0x000000000045e083 in CSipPhone::on_call_state (call_id=2, e=<value optimized out>)
```

As we see, the crash happens in the HuffmanEnd. But I don't understand why the ~RecorderSession is called twice although I use code "delete this" to delete the RecorderSession object as below:
    int RecorderSession::OnHangup()
    {
       delete this;
       return 0;
    }

So does the "delete this" cause this phenomenon?

Comment: How are we supposed to know? We have no idea what your code looks like.

Comment: I do not think you should have `delete this` in your code

Comment: and the code is.... where?

Answer (score 0):

The chances are that your function `OnHangup` itself is already being called from the destructor of the object in question. Thus you are calling `delete` on yourself when the object is already in the middle of being destroyed, causing the double delete.

Comment: It's more likely he's `delete`ing something that wasn't dynamically allocated, or doing so then doing so again later.

Comment: The RecorderSession object is dynamically allocated. The OnHangup isn't  called in destructor. This crash doesn't occur every once,but only one time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your object is created by placement new, or as a local object on the stack, or as a namespace-scope / global, or as a member of another object.

In that case Dtor will be called one more time.